# App cannot be installed on Xperia Z3

Tags: applications, installation, sms-blocking, sony-xperia-z3

I found an Android chess app with network [here](http://www.aartbik.com/MISC/android.html) but I can't install it.

For an unknown reason, the installation requires the program to be able to send SMS. 
When I try to install this app (I trust the author of the app), the installation program warns me and ask me if I really want to install the program; I click on "Install" but nothing happens. It's an Xperia Z3 and the installation from unknown sources is allowed.

On Archos 50 Helium, the installation works though. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well the application may not contain **graphic activity**, it may contains **background services**, or **broadcastreviver** that work on background I mean in **hide mode**.

Comment: can you please edit your answer to be more clear

Comment: i m unable to edit my question because i have no privileges to edit...

Comment: type it as a comment and i will edit it for you